# How do I call the multi aim constraint from the children of my armature?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to call the multi aim constraint from the children of my armature to turn it off when my character is not aiming, but unlike other components, when I call it, it just puts a red squigly line under it.

My hierarchy goes like this:

PlayerArmature > Geometry > Armature (prefab) > Skeleton (prefab) > Rig 1 > body aim (this is where the component I want to call is)

Comment: In what way do you call/try to call it the moment that you get the result you described? Isn't any standard way (exposing field in inspector, navigating transform hierarchy from code and calling GetComponent, getting reference from code from other script) working?

Comment: anytime I write it's name it puts a red squigly line under it. ex: this will work `public Rigidbody rigidbody` but this wont `public MultiAimConstraint multiAimConstraint`

Comment: Only now did I realize what do you mean by this line... and if you hover your mouse over it what is the error message?

Comment: the error was `type or namespace 'MultiAimConstraint" could not be found` also It doesn't show up when I start writing it's name.

Comment: Maybe you got this MultiAimConstraint in some namespace, and you need to add using directive? Try searching for exactly that error message, there is a ton of stuff about this problem already.

Comment: can you tell me how? I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you include

```
using UnityEngine.Animations.Rigging;
```

to avoid the namespace not found error.